Best way to structure your store for large number of state values in Zustand
So, here is a little bit of context: I am very new to Zustand and wanted to try it, so I decided to use it in my car app project. In the project, I have car filtering functionality where I have many filters of different types. The structure is as follows:
export interface CarFilters {
  location?: Location[];
  carModel?: CarModel[];
  priceRange?: FilterRange<number>;
  modelYearRange?: FilterRange<number>;
  kilometersDriven?: FilterRange<number>;
  registeredIn?: Location;
  trustedCars?: TrustedCars[];
  transmission?: Transmission;
  bodyColor?: string[];
  fuelType?: FuelType[];
  engineCapacity?: FilterRange<number>;
  assembly?: Assembly;
  bodyType?: BodyType[];
  modelCategory?: ModelCategory[];
  sellerType?: SellerType;
  numberOfDoors?: NumberOfDoors;
  seatingCapacity?: SeatingCapacity;
  adProperties?: AdProperties[];
  searchQuery?: string;
}

so, I was wondering what is the best way to structure your store should I make one filter state and set it when any of the value in it changes or should I make each filter an individual state and have a setter for that? Also, I want two very specific features:

One is I want to show in the app what filters are currently being
applied for example if there are values in the location array or car
model array I want to show them in active filters
Second is I want to show the count of these active filters someplace
else.

What is the best and performant way to do this and what are the things I need to take care of so that I don't end up rerendering more than required? A detailed explanation would be a great help.

why not keep the filter states in url? If you're using vanilla react, you must be using react-router. You  can use useSearchParams hook to easily keep a track of query params in  url.

Well I am not using react, I am using it in react-native.
